# how do i add a selector change event to this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jquery which works great

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#new_average, #max_occupancy').keyup(function(){
        factor = $(".industry_picker option:checked").attr("title");
        average = $('#new_average').val();
        if($('#new_average').val().indexOf("$") != -1){
            average = average.substring(1);                                                     
        }
        if($("#max_occupancy").val() != ""){
            max_occupancy = $("#max_occupancy").val();
            max_total = ((average * factor) * max_occupancy) * 30;
            if(factor != ""){
                $("#new_calc").val("$" + max_total + ".00");
            }

        }                                                   
    });
});
```

but the problems is I need this to fire off on keyup and on

```
 $(".industry_picker")
```

changed ....i know I can copy this exact functionality over and have a

```
 $(".industry_picker").change
```

but i feel that is a hack...is there a better way of having the

```
$('#new_average, #max_occupancy").keyup
```

and

```
$(".industry_picker").change
```

in the same selector or a better way of achieving this without copying the entire function again

Comment: **Off-topic**, but: Do you have all those variables declared somewhere? 'Cause it looks like you're setting yourself up to fall prey to the *[Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use an anonymous function.

```
function myCallback(){
    factor = $(".industry_picker option:checked").attr("title");
    average = $('#new_average').val();
    if($('#new_average').val().indexOf("$") != -1){
        average = average.substring(1);                                                     
    }
    if($("#max_occupancy").val() != ""){
        max_occupancy = $("#max_occupancy").val();
        max_total = ((average * factor) * max_occupancy) * 30;
        if(factor != ""){
            $("#new_calc").val("$" + max_total + ".00");
        }

    }
}

$('#new_average, #max_occupancy').keyup(myCallback);
$('.industry_picker').change(myCallback);
```

***Side note:*** you're not using `var` anywhere, which means that there is only **one** copy of each of these variables: `factor`, `average`, `max_occupancy`, and `max_total`. Introducing global state is sloppy coding and makes programs harder to maintain and debug. **Declare your variables with `var`.**

Recommended reading: [MDC `var` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: +1 Though nit-picking the wording, the problem isn't that the function is *anonymous*, it's that it's not reused. (You can reuse anonymous functions, people do it all the time, though I prefer to help my tools help me by giving my functions names.) Nit-picking, I know. ;-)

Comment: thanks guys....one question...does the function need to be in a document.ready or will anywhere on the page work

Comment: @Tamer: you can declare the function in any scope that's accessible from the document ready handler. In general, it's nice to declare functions and variables in non-global scopes to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @Tamer: Anywhere where its symbol is in-scope where you hook up the handlers, which means either at global scope or within an enclosing function call (like your `ready` handler). Note that putting it in your ready handler prevents it being added to the global namespace, which is a good thing if this is the only place you're using it. (I usually put the entire logic of pages inside a single enclosing function, exposing no public symbols at all.)

Comment: @T.J.: how would I reuse an anonymous function? Something like this? `var foo = function () {...};`

Comment: @Matt: That would be one way. Or assign it to a property on an object and use it from there (people -- including the jQuery team -- do that a *lot*). Or hook it up to the `keyup` event and then use `$('.industry_picker').change(function() { $(this).keyup(); });`. (*--shudder--*, I know, but I've actually had people argue that that was good practice, though never cogently.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$('#new_average, #max_occupancy').keyup(Myfunction);

$(".industry_picker").change(Myfunction);

function Myfunction(){
factor = $(".industry_picker option:checked").attr("title");
    average = $('#new_average').val();
    if($('#new_average').val().indexOf("$") != -1){
        average = average.substring(1);                                                     
    }
    if($("#max_occupancy").val() != ""){
        max_occupancy = $("#max_occupancy").val();
        max_total = ((average * factor) * max_occupancy) * 30;
        if(factor != ""){
            $("#new_calc").val("$" + max_total + ".00");
        }

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't assign your function directly to the event handler, but to a local variable ans assign that to both:

```
var myHandler = function() { ... };
$('#new_average, #max_occupancy').keyup(myHandler);
$(".industry_picker').change(myHandler);
```